# Is it possible to "freeze" a Set (or Map)?

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary, set

While `Set` is an Object, `Object.freeze()` works on the object's properties, which evidently Map and Set do not use: eg

```
let m = new Map();
Object.freeze(m);
m.set('key', 55);
m.get('key'); // ==> 55
```

This is the behavior in Chrome, and I expect it's standard.

I understand that one could (sometimes) transform the Set or Map into a normal Object, and then freeze the object but then key access changes between the unfrozen and frozen version.

Comment: What Set and Map do you use ? I have not seen such  in JavaScript

Comment: @MaxZoom: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Does not look good for mobile browsers.

Comment: @MaxZoom Unless you transpile it to ES5 with something like Babel and/or use a polyfill.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question, but doesn't currently seem like a directly supported feature on a `Set` or `Map` object.

Here are some work-arounds I can think of using the `Set` object as a guide:

1. You could create a proxy object that removed `.add()`, `.clear()` and `.delete()`, but allowed proxied access to all other methods that just read data.  This would hide access to the actual `Set` object so there would be no way to access it directly and provide proxied access to all other methods.
2. You could override `.add()`, `.clear()` and `.delete()` on a given `Set` instance with methods that did nothing or threw an exception which would prevent modification.  If you made those override methods non-configurable and then did a `.freeze()` on the object, those methods couldn't be put back.  One could use `Set.prototype.add` directly on the `Set` object to still bypass it though.

Comment: thanks. agree. the first seems a lot of work and one loses `instanceof Set`. on the second, overriding `.add()` etc, seems easier, having it fail silently or raise error. as far as "still bypass", for me the main advantage of freezing is not absolute security but rather protecting myself, much like typing variables.

Comment: A couple years old now, but I thought I'd mention that solution #2 would work best if you overrode the listed methods with undefined, not methods. That would throw an error if you attempted to call them as methods, and would be easiest for one-offs. If you want a more general solution with a subclassed Set or Map, bear in mind that these don't work properly when subclassed in all browsers, so the proxy in #1 is a better reusable approach.